# How to catch TO_TIMESTAMP or TO_DATE exceptions in PLSQL without an OTHERS clause?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I noticed that `TO_TIMESTAMP` raises a variety of error codes depending on how it failed;

```
--01847
select to_timestamp('2016-01-0a', 'yyyy-MM-dd') from dual;
--01858
select to_timestamp('2016-01-aa', 'yyyy-MM-dd') from dual;
--01843
select to_timestamp('2016-15-01', 'yyyy-MM-dd') from dual;
```

Given that it doesn't raise a single error code, how can I catch the error without resorting to using the catch-all `OTHERS`:

```
DECLARE
    foo timestamp;
BEGIN
    select to_timestamp('2016-01-0a', 'yyyy-MM-dd') into foo from dual;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('bad date');
END;
```

Comment: Thanks Matthew.  I wondered what version of oracle you are using?  If on 12cR2, the `validate_conversion` function may be of interest if you.

Comment: One other question I wasn't sure from your post.  Are you also looking to avoid multiple exception blocks (multiple `EXCEPTION_INIT` for the different exceptions) or only to avoid `WHEN OTHERS`?  Thanks

Comment: @alexgibbs Unfortunately I'm on 12cR1 but we should be upgrading sooner or later so I will look out for it. Ideally it would be nice to catch a single exception for all possible errors originating out of `to_timestamp` caused by an incorrect date string in addition to avoiding `WHEN OTHERS` but I'm not sure if that is possible.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on 12cR2, then you can use `VALIDATE_CONVERSION` to check the validity of a potential type conversion before making the conversion and avoid the exception entirely.

In earlier versions, you could create your own equivalent function for `TIMESTAMP`s that attempts the conversion and handles the exceptions.  You could declare each exception-type of interest individually and log/handle the failure-modes of interest separately for each as needed, with an overall `WHEN OTHERS` for the stuff you don't care about or want to log/handle:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION IS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT_OK(P_TIMESTAMP_TEXT IN VARCHAR2, P_FORMAT IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'yyyy-MM-dd')
  RETURN BOOLEAN
IS
  --exception names
  V_TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP;
    DAY_OF_MONTH EXCEPTION;
    NON_NUMERIC EXCEPTION;
  --etc.
PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (DAY_OF_MONTH, -1847);
PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (NON_NUMERIC, -1858);
  BEGIN
    V_TIMESTAMP := to_timestamp(P_TIMESTAMP_TEXT, P_FORMAT);
    RETURN TRUE;
    EXCEPTION WHEN DAY_OF_MONTH
    THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The day of month must be between...');
    RETURN FALSE;
    WHEN NON_NUMERIC
    THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Non-Numeric data was found...');
    RETURN FALSE;
    --etc.
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(UTL_LMS.FORMAT_MESSAGE('Unexpected timestamp problem: %s', SQLERRM));
    RETURN FALSE;
  END;
/
```

Then you can log/handle the types of interest:

```
DECLARE
  V_CHECK BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
  V_CHECK := IS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT_OK('2016010a');
  V_CHECK := IS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT_OK('2016-01-aa');
  V_CHECK := IS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT_OK('2016-01-0a');
  IF IS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT_OK('2014-01-01')
  THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('It is ok.  Yay');
  END IF;
END;
/

Unexpected timestamp problem: ORA-01862: the numeric value does not match the
length of the format item
Non-Numeric data was found...
The day of month must be between...
It is ok.  Yay
```

Or if you don't care about logging/handle different failure modes and just want to prevent broad exception-catching, you can go ahead and use `WHEN OTHERS`, but in isolated scope:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION 
  IS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT_OK(P_TIMESTAMP_TEXT IN VARCHAR2, P_FORMAT IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'yyyy-MM-dd')
  RETURN BOOLEAN
IS
  V_TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP;
  BEGIN
    V_TIMESTAMP := to_timestamp(P_TIMESTAMP_TEXT, P_FORMAT);
    RETURN TRUE;
    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RETURN FALSE;
  END;
/
```

Or Inline:

```
DECLARE
  V_MY_TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP;
  BEGIN
  -- some other code ...

  BEGIN
    V_MY_TIMESTAMP := to_timestamp('2016-01-aa', 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL;
  END;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('My Timestamp:'||V_MY_TIMESTAMP);

END;
/

My Timestamp:
```

Comment: Thanks. I might just have to settle for the suggestion of using `WHEN OTHERS` in an isolated scope until we can upgrade to 12cR2. Would you happen to know where I can find a list of all possible error codes thrown by to_timestamp in case I want to try the comprehensive route?

Comment: Thanks @MatthewMoisen.  I haven't come across a comprehensive list of timestamp conversion exceptions before.  That is a good question; I'd be very interested in seeing it as well if you can find one.  Actually a comprehensive list of throwable exceptions seems like it would have utility for most oracle-provided functions.   Please let me know if you find anything good.  Thanks

Comment: 1+ for using `UTL_LMS.FORMAT_MESSAGE`